# How to create trigger inside an IF condition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger on a table. My requirement is to create trigger only when the table exists.

e.g.

```
if(table exists)
        begin
             create trigger on the table 
        end
```

After googling, I found that `create trigger` should be first command in the batch. 
That means I can not use the `if` or any other thing in the current batch.

Please, help me out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('YourTable','U') IS NOT NULL)
    EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER ....')
```

You will need to escape any single quotes in the trigger body by doubling them up.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the create trigger statement on it's own.

If there is no table, it will not do anything to the database, just give an error message. Nothing bad will happen.

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER Foo ON  DoesNotExist AFTER INSERT AS SELECT 1` returns error `The object 'DoesNotExist' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.`

Comment: @MartinSmith, yes, of course it does. But nothing BAD happens. What you want is no trigger. What you get is no trigger. If there is a table, what you want is a trigger and what you get is a trigger. Problem solved.

Comment: Except your deployment scripts then have loads of spurious errors that you need to inspect to see if they were expected or not.

Comment: @Ben: it will break the executions , if combined with other scripts.

Comment: @Raja_Chandan, then you should have put that in the question.

Comment: @Ben I hope I never work on one of your projects. Errors as a normal thing is a pain in the ass to deal with.